# ASP.Net C# - need help with recursion, parent/child relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, recursion

Trying to find an elegant solution for a problem in my CMS system.  If someone moves a page, I need all the child pages to also be changed.  Simplified database is like this:

```
id     url              parent        level
1      page.aspx         0             0
2      page2.aspx        0             0
3      page.aspx         1             1
4      page.aspx         1             1
5      page.aspx         3             2
6      page.aspx         3             2
```

If I decide to move id 3 to have 2 as a parent instead of 1, I need to change all of the url's for the child pages.

Is there a simple(ish) recursive technique I can use for this?

Thanks

Comment: are you looking for SQL solution or C#?

Comment: why do save the level of the page? It is depending on the other data. BTW, you are talking about a tree, not recursion.

Comment: Why do you need to change all the urls? A solutions depends on the situation. You need to provide more information in what way the urls are used.

Comment: For level property appareantly (it can be stored in the database for performance reasons although i would use it with care)

Comment: Your page name should reflect the page's content, not sure why you want level in it. Best way to store the level is using a sitemap. If you use a sitemap, you can simply move the page node to the new parent, and your're done.

Comment: Ok, it's quite an old system I'm updating - the level was originally put in there to help with generating a tree and knowing where I am in the hierarchy. It's not really important for this, I just thought it might help illustrate.  The URL is the field I need to change - does it really matter why it's there?  If you must know its so that you have a fallback url if the user doesn't assign a friendly url to the page, so you can still do page1.aspx?i=3 or whatever.

Comment: Sll, I'd like a code solution if possible rather than pure SQL.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
void IncrementUrlLevel(UrlCollection collection, UrlEntry entry){
    if (entry == null)
        return;

    foreach (UrlEntry childEntry in collection){
        if (childEntry.Parent == entry.Id){
            IncrementUrlLeven(collection, childEntry);
        }
    }

    entry.Level++;
}
```